# Change font color for a part of text in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have cells which will contain the below value

```
"Image not allowed|png"
```

I want to change the color of **|png** alone or whatever comes after **"|"**

Now i am trying to change the font color using the below code

```
Cells(4,2).Font.Color = RGB(255, 50, 25)
```

It will change the entire cells font color, Is it possible to change only the selected text color(`|png`) using VBA?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `Characters` cell's property like :

```
Cells(1,1).Characters(Start:=2, Length:=3).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
```

This should be a good start :

```
Sub vignesh()
Dim StartChar As Integer, _
    LenColor As Integer

For i = 1 To 5
    With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
        StartChar = InStr(1, .Value, "|")
        If StartChar <> 0 Then
            LenColor = Len(.Value) - StartChar + 1
            .Characters(Start:=StartChar, Length:=LenColor).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 12):

Yes this is possible.  A good way to explore the Excel object model is to use the macro recorder to record a macro where you manually carry out the manipulation you're interested in.

In this case, you can use:

```
Cell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=5).Font
```

to set font properties of a substring in a cell.

Comment: This is much more straightforward than the accepted answer.  Also note that the [argument names](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments) (`Start:=` and `Length:=`) are not necessary in this case (since they are the only 2 arguments of the [`Characters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters) property.)  So we could simply use, for example, `Range("A1").Characters(4, 2).Font.Color = vbBlue`

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible to change only the selected text color

Simple

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()
    With Selection.Font
        .ColorIndex = 3 
    End With
End Sub
```