# Copy data in three Excel cells and paste into fourth with font color changed for each of the three

Tags: python, excel

I have a Excel sheet with some data and am trying to copy data in three cells and paste it into a fourth with the font color changed for each, thus:

[image]

I'm able to copy the contents but not able to change the font color of each cell.

I have to **do it using python module win32com.**

Comment: I don't know the Python module, but this is how changing color for parts of a cell works in VBA : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567552/change-font-color-for-a-part-of-text-in-cell/30567820#30567820 Also, can you **add your code in the post** (edit : http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33519409/edit ) so that **we can improve it** and not start from scratch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following script should work. It takes an existing `Book1.xlsx` and copies the contents of the cells `A1:C1` into `D1` and adjusts the color of each. The updated data is written to a new file called `Output.xlsx`:

```
import win32com.client as win32
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'Book1.xlsx')
ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

cells = ws.Range("A1:C1").Value[0]
ws.Range("D1").Value = ' '.join(cells)

offset = 0
for cell, color in zip(cells, [3, 4, 5]):
    ws.Range("D1").GetCharacters(offset, len(cell)+1).Font.ColorIndex = color
    offset += len(cell) + 1

wb.SaveAs(r'Output.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Note, you will probably need to include full paths to your files.

Tested using Python 2.7.6