# Replace Text and Change font color

Tags: vba, excel, replace, fonts

I'm stuck. I was successfully able to replace 3 texts in a column to a specific text. But am unable to change the font of the replaced texts to Red. Would appreciate help. Thanks
Following is the current code

```
Worksheets("HPR").Columns("E").Replace _
What:="IM", Replacement:="Non-IM", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

Worksheets("HPR").Columns("E").Replace _
What:="Comp", Replacement:="Non-IM", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True

Worksheets("HPR").Columns("E").Replace _
What:="", Replacement:="Non-IM", _
SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True"
```

Comment: You can refer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567552/change-font-color-for-a-part-of-text-in-cell

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the below lines to the beginning of your code.

```
With Application.ReplaceFormat.Font
    .Subscript = False
    .Color = 255
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
```

Now add the below line after all the `MatchCase:=True,`

```
ReplaceFormat:=True
```

Comment: that's perfect @sn152