# Change font color for variable as part of text in cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am struggling with VBA macro which should color part of the text.

The macro looks like

```
Sub Note()
        Dim c As Range
        Dim val As String
        Set c = ActiveCell
        val = InputBox("Add note", "Note text")
            If IsEmpty(c.Value) = True Then
                c.Value = Format(Now(), "DD MMM YY Hh:Nn") & ": " & val
            Else
                c.Value = c.Value & Chr(10) & Format(Now(), "DD MMM YY Hh:Nn") & ": " & val
        End If
        End Sub
```

And I want to achieve that Now() will be red and rest of text will be green.

I tried to play with .Font.Color = vbRed etc but without any luck

I also look on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567552/change-font-color-for-a-part-of-text-in-cell) but it not quite what I wanted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You linked an answer but you weren't using what was in there, why?

Try this :

```
Sub Note()
Dim c As Range
Dim val As String
Dim StartChar As Integer, _
    LenColor As Integer
Set c = ActiveCell

val = InputBox("Add note", "Note text")

With c
    .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    If IsEmpty(.Value) = True Then
        StartChar = 1
        LenColor = Len("DD MMM YY Hh:Nn")
        .Value = Format(Now(), "DD MMM YY Hh:Nn") & ": " & val
        .Characters(Start:=StartChar, Length:=LenColor).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Else
        StartChar = Len(.Value) + 1
        LenColor = Len("DD MMM YY Hh:Nn")
        .Value = .Value & Chr(10) & Format(Now(), "DD MMM YY Hh:Nn") & ": " & val
        .Characters(Start:=StartChar, Length:=LenColor).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    End If
End With 'c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works fine for first insert, but if I use it once more It will mark all text with red

Comment: @user7410242 : This will do! I added a line to reset the initial color to black, so it'll work properly now

Answer (score 3):

Try like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Note()

    Dim c           As Range
    Dim val         As String: val = "vit"
    Dim lngLen      As Long

    Set c = ActiveCell
    c.Value = Format(Now(), "DD MMM YY Hh:Nn") & ": " & val
    lngLen = Len(Format(Now(), "DD MMM YY Hh:Nn"))

    c.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=lngLen).Font.Color = vbRed

End Sub
```

I have removed the input box, but you can return it easily. It gives probably what you want.Pretty much, it asks for the length of the Now() format and it colors the first N signs in the formula in red, following the logic from the question you have mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Sub Note()
Dim c As Range
Dim val As String
Dim lngPos As Integer
Set c = ActiveCell
val = InputBox("Add note", "Note text")
c.Value = ""
    If IsEmpty(c.Value) = True Then
        c.Value = Format(Now(), "DD MMM YY Hh:Nn") & " - " & val
        lngPos = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, " - ")
        With ActiveCell.Font
            .ColorIndex = 4
        End With
        With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=lngPos - 1).Font
            .ColorIndex = 3 'or .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
    Else
        c.Value = c.Value & Chr(10) & Format(Now(), "DD MMM YY Hh:Nn") & " - " & val 
        lngPos = InStr(ActiveCell.Value, " - ")
        With ActiveCell.Font
            .ColorIndex = 4
        End With
        With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=lngPos - 1).Font
            .ColorIndex = 3 'or .Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works fine for first insert, but if I use it once more It will mark all text with red

Comment: @pokemon_Man : You forgot to remove `c.Value = ""` before the `If` ;)

Comment: @R3uK depends if user7410232 wants to display the same insert on top of the same insert again and again or just one insert per cell each time the input is asked ect. IMO, i think one insert per input should be the way to go which this code does. resets cell string to blank and do the color again.