# Add text before VBA function display

Tags: vba, excel

I have Excel formula macro that display last saved file time

```
Function LastModified() As Date
LastModified = ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Function
```

In cell B5 I call it out in a following format

```
=LastModified()
```

It returns the following data: "43070.58675"
which I convert using Format Cell option to a date and time format "01/12/2017 12:38"

However I would like to add a text "Last modified: " before this function in the same cell B5.

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the `Text` function to format it like so:

```
="Last Modified " & TEXT(LastModified(), "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm")
```

Comment: Is there a chance to embed also a different font colour to this function format as well ?
Last Modified: - white colour and date with time displayed in red or orange colour

Comment: Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 3, where 3 is the colorindex for Red or 45 for Orange

Comment: How to incorporate this formatting into formula provided by @Tim Wilkinson ?

Comment: @Xabier that doesn't really fit with the OP question.

That can be done but not using this method, nor your original question, you would probably have to have a `Worksheet_Change` function to check the cell contents use `LastModified()` then split the characters to have different colors. Google "VBA on cell change' then look at this https://vbadud.wordpress.com/2007/11/03/excel-vba-change-font-color-for-part-of-text/ . Have a play then post a new question if you get stuck.

Comment: Or thinking about it just incorporate the link I posted into your custom function, probably much easier.

Comment: I will have a play with changing the color and update my answer shortly.

Comment: you can't change the color of *part* of a **formula result**

Comment: However, if @Omen change his logic and switch from formula to pure VBA - it's would work. There's no idea behind that formula anyway, because `LastModified` will change only on Save event, hence you can populate a cell *once* on save via VBA, which is better than calculate each time same thing over and over.

Answer (score 2):

If other cells use `B5` in formulas, you can retain the *DateTime* data type and add a title with a **custom number format**:

> **<sub>Right Click → `Format Cells...` → `Number` tab → `Custom`</sub>**
>
> Type:
>
> ```
>        "Last Modified: "h:mm AM/PM
> ```

---

If you want to change the original formula so that it will always return `Last modified: 01/12/2017 12:38` (as text) then it's as simple as:

```
Function LastModified() As String
    LastModified = "Last Modified: " & ActiveWorkbook.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Last Save Time")
End Function
```

Comment: I was hoping you could change the colour of just the text, but it's all part of the positive number format.  So `[Red] "Last Modified: "#,##0;[Blue]-#,##0` would display _Last Modified: 5_ in red, but _-5_ in blue.

Comment: correct, you can't change the color of part of a formula result.  Are you not able to just insert a column?

Comment: That would be the easiest answer.  I was just wondering if you could do it with formatting as I've never tried.  Was pretty certain you couldn't, but you never know until you try.

Comment: I guess you **could** do it if there wasn't a formula in the cell, like if you had a command button or event that would put text in the cell programmatically, and then color part of the cell like this: [color part of text in a cell with vba]( https://stackoverflow.com/a/30567820/8112776)  ...would have been handy if this kind of info was in the question!

Comment: Yes, can definitely do it using the using `Characters`.  But as @CommonSense said in his comment on the accepted answer - it's only updated when the workbook is saved so may as well use pure VBA.