# Change font color for certain text in MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have very little VBA experience and a have a large document that contains the text similar to below:

> "(+12.3%) which translates to (-$78.9M)"

Kind of similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567552/change-font-color-for-a-part-of-text-in-cell) I want to change text that follows the symbol "+" or "-" to green and red respectively, while keeping text black.

Is it possible for a VBA code that can automatically do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with two *wildcard* Find/Replace operations, without recourse to a macro, using:

```
Find = +[0-9.%$M]{1,}
Replace = ^&
```

with the replacement font colour set to green, and

```
Find = \-[0-9.%$M]{1,}
Replace = ^&
```

with the replacement font colour set to red. You could, of course, use the macro recorder to create a single macro containing both operations.