# Get unique strings from cells and change its color

Tags: excel, vba

I've below code which gives count of unique strings separated by comma. Now I want to apply unique color to each unique strings listed in `E` column. I'm unable to find how to get values from dictionary collection.

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range, delim As String
Dim e       As Variant
Dim s       As Variant
lr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & lr)

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1
    For Each e In rng.Value
        If Trim$(e) <> "" Then
            For Each s In Split(e, ",")
                If Trim$(s) <> "" Then .Item(Trim$(s)) = Empty
            Next s
        End If
    Next e
    MsgBox .Count
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You only add keys to your dictionary and the value is always `Empty` because of `.Item(Trim$(s)) = Empty`. So, question is, what do you rellay want to add as value to the dictionay?

Comment: But it seems to return correct no. of unique string. I'm not familier with `dictionary`. I just want to color each unique string in `E` column. Input is in `C` and `E` column.

Comment: Yes, because you use a feature of a dictionary which will only add a key to the dictionary unless it does not alreay exist. In the other case it will change the value. I also do not see any code in your post where you color anything. And why is 5456 and 1111 in your screenshot in one cell in column E?

Comment: What I've is C and E column with data. I thought from C column we can get easily count of unique strings (which posted code does) and from that strings in E column can be colored. E column is the summary so it may have many strings in a cell.

Comment: So, again, I do not see any code where you try to color the strings. What is the question you have?

Comment: Looking for the same, I've manually done it.

Comment: So, you want us to give you the code?

Comment: If possible or hint.

Comment: As you obviously do not understand the code you posted it might be a good idea to get familiar with dicitionaries for a start, look [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/). Then try to come up with an attempt to solve your original problem and then someone might be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started. Comments in the code explains what it does. To set the font color of text in a cell, see [Change font color for a part of text in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567552/change-font-color-for-a-part-of-text-in-cell).

```
Sub test()

    Dim rng As Range, delim As String
    Dim e As Variant
    Dim s As Variant
    lr = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & lr)

    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

        .CompareMode = 1

        ' Build dictionary of unique elements.
        For Each e In rng.Value
            e = Trim$(e)
            If e <> "" Then
                If InStr(e, ",") Then
                    For Each s In Split(e, ",")
                        If Trim$(s) <> "" Then .Item(Trim$(s)) = Empty
                    Next s
                ElseIf InStr(e, vbLf) Then ' You missed this case where values are separated by a linefeed.
                    For Each s In Split(e, vbLf)
                        If Trim$(s) <> "" Then .Item(Trim$(s)) = Empty
                    Next s
                Else
                   .Item(e) = Empty
                End If
            End If
        Next e

        ' Array of available colors.
        Dim colors(3)
        colors(0) = vbBlack
        colors(1) = vbRed
        colors(2) = vbGreen
        colors(3) = vbBlue

        ' Assign color to each element in the dictionary,
        ' the value of the dictionary is the color of the element.
        Dim i As Integer
        i = 0

        For Each e In keys
            keys.Item(e) = colors(i)
            i = (i + 1) Mod 4
        Next e

        ' Parse again elements in rng, this time setting its color based
        ' on color found in dictionary.
        For Each e In rng.Value
            e = Trim$(e)
            If e <> "" Then
                If InStr(e, ",") Then
                    For Each s In Split(e, ",")
                        If Trim$(s) <> "" Then
                            ' Set color of Trim$(s) in current cell to .Item(Trim$(s)).
                        End If
                    Next s
                ElseIf InStr(e, vbLf) Then
                    For Each s In Split(e, vbLf)
                        If Trim$(s) <> "" Then
                            ' Set color of Trim$(s) in current cell to .Item(Trim$(s)).
                        End If
                    Next s
                Else
                    ' Set color of e in current cell to .Item(e).
                End If
            End If
        Next e

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Experimenter - Did this help?

Comment: At `.Item(Trim$(s)) = Empty` giving error `Run time error 424 - Object required`

Comment: @Experimenter - This statement appears on multiple lines.

Comment: at 1st instance occurs. Values are: `e="5454, 5363", s="5454"`

Comment: @Experimenter - I can only tell you to check your code carefully because this used to work. Error most likely means that dictionary has not been created.

Comment: I just breaked line `With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary").CompareMode = 1` into 2 and error gone. New error at line `For Each k In Keys` : `Run-time error 13: Type mismatch`

Comment: @Experimenter - Change `k` for `e` because `k` has not been declared. I updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved with below approach. Data was in "E" column. I managed to get the unique numbers in "G" column through code and then using those I applied color back to "E" column numbers.

[image]

```
Sub HyperlinkPRs()
Dim rng As Range, delim As String
Dim e       As Variant
Dim s       As Variant
lr = Worksheets("RawData").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = Worksheets("RawData").Range("E2:E" & lr)

Range("G:G").ClearContents

With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    .CompareMode = 1
    For Each e In rng.Value
    lg = Worksheets("RawData").Cells(Rows.Count, 7).End(xlUp).Row
        If Trim$(e) <> "" Then
            For Each s In Split(e, ",")
                If Trim$(s) <> "" Then .Item(Trim$(s)) = Empty
        Cells(lg + 1, 7).Value = s
            Next s
        End If
    Next e

End With

Columns(7).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1) '''delete duplicates

Call COlorPRs
End Sub
Sub COlorPRs() ''' https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1030392-vba-color-format-text-string.html
    Dim colorKey As Range, toColorRange As Range, tCR As Range, cK As Range

Set colorKey = Range("G2:G13")
Set toColorRange = Range("E1:E1200")
    For Each tCR In toColorRange     'loop though all cells of to be color range
        If tCR.Value <> "" Then 'skip blanks
        For Each cK In colorKey   ' loop through all cells of color key
            If cK.Value <> "" Then ' skip blanks
                Dim foundNum As Integer
                foundNum = 1
                m = cK.Row
                Do
                    foundNum = InStr(foundNum, tCR.Value, cK.Value, vbTextCompare)
                    If foundNum <> 0 Then
                        If m = 5 Then ''' To avoid yelloish color which is hard to see
                            m = 54
                        ElseIf m = 26 Then
                            m = 55
                        Else
                            m = m
                        End If
                            tCR.Characters(Start:=foundNum, Length:=Len(cK.Value)).Font.ColorIndex = m + 1
                           foundNum = foundNum + 1
                    End If
                Loop Until foundNum = 0  'keep looping though all characters
            End If
        Next cK
        End If
    Next tCR

End Sub
```