# Font color of formula input

Tags: excel, fonts, formula

Formula is `="film length of film titanic is "&I2`
So how do I change color only to cell I2 value different than rest of the text. Is there a function or macro or any way?

Comment: Does it have to be a formula like that? Is it only for visualization or do you use this value to something else later?

Comment: If you allow a vba solution, check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567552/change-font-color-for-a-part-of-text-in-cell

Answer (score 0):

You need to first convert the formula into a value:

1. copy the cell containing the formula
2. PasteSpecialValues back onto the cell
3. hi-light the section of text in the Formula Bar and apply the color

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textbox and place that at the position you want.
That way the textbox is "floating" in the cell and you can change the text color of the text box to what you want.

It won't be perfect but it kind off does what you want.

[image]
[image]

Select the textbox and click in the formula field and type `=I2`