# Excel - conditionally format text within parentheses only

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

The conditional formatting should be applied on the text inside the parentheses only. The formula should also be based on what's inside the parentheses (0 = black, < 0 = red, > 0 = green).

Is this possible without VBA? If not, a VBA solution would be okay.

[image]

What it should look like in a PPT report:

[image]

Comment: It's not possible without vba I don't think. And if you need VBA, you'd have to be more specific about what problem you ran into while coding this.

Comment: As @JvdV stated I also don't think you can do this without vba. Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567552/change-font-color-for-a-part-of-text-in-cell) and update your question with code if you're still having problems.

Comment: Is the text to be processed a string, like it looks or a peculiar formatting of a number? Is the cell value the result of a formula, or is  it manually written?

Comment: Why would you want to run into all this trouble? Just add an extra column and do the conditional formatting there.

Comment: There is a reason for this formatting, I concatenated them using Power Query (M), loaded it in Excel spreadsheet, and will link it in PowerPoint ( a report), that is why I don't want that extra column. I just uploaded that layout in PPT report above.

Comment: So, is it a string?

Comment: Q: Is the text to be processed a string? - ANSWER: Yes, it's a string already

Comment: So, again, why can't you keep the extra column in PPT as well unless your boss is telling you to do it excatly like that ;-)

Comment: good point Storax. Have you seen the image above? It looks more clean, does it not? I guess I can make some changes to the report if I need to. But I don't mind writing a VBA code (I know some VBA) either to stick with the old layout (if they require me to).

Comment: Reports are often a matter of taste and if you want to do it like that go ahead.

Comment: Thanks Storax. It is 2021 so I will be doing a lot of changes to my reports (if I can). Happy New Year by the way.

Comment: Just for the record. Those who downvoted your question do not vote because they "hate". It's a simple matter of quality of the question. Seeking help without showing your own attempt implies that you are simly asking someone to hand you the solution. This attracts downvotes. Btw, while I personally didn't downvote, I did vote to close the question due the the above. See [ask] a question with an [mcve] for some reference. I hope that helps you out in the future may you ask another question =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next way, please. The range to be conditionally formatted is "C1:C5", like I could deduce from your sample, but it can be adapted for any position. The code can also calculate the last cell of it:

```
Sub condFormattingStringParant()
 Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, c As Range
 
 Set sh = ActiveSheet
 Set rng = sh.Range("C1:C5")
 For Each c In rng.cells
    If Not FormatCond(c) Then
        MsgBox "In cell " & c.Address & " no parentheses pattern could be found..."
    End If
 Next
End Sub

Function FormatCond(c As Range) As Boolean
    Dim vComp As Double, ar, startCh As Long, lngth As Long, col As Long
    
    startCh = InStr(c.Value, "(") + 1
    If startCh = 1 Then FormatCond = False: Exit Function
    ar = Split(c.Value, "(")
    lngth = Len(ar(1)) - 1
    
    vComp = CDbl(left(ar(1), Len(ar(1)) - 1))
    Select Case vComp
        Case Is > 0
             col = RGB(0, 150, 90)
        Case Is = 0
            col = vbBlack
        Case Else
            col = vbRed
    End Select
    c.Characters(startCh, lngth).Font.Color = col: FormatCond = True
End Function
```

Please, test it and send some feedback

Comment: I forgot to tell you that my C4:C8 range is a formula (so it can be refreshed every month, linked to a table which is linked to a Power Query) and not really a hardcoded string) but I will make a workaround by pasting values in another column first before running your code. It works well but I think I need to edit vbGreen to dark green. I will look for the hex code of the desired green color.

Comment: Your solution works like a charm. I know I need to polish my working file but I appreciate the help. Thank you so much for the solution FaneDuru. I will take it from here.

Comment: @Stuck At Home Overflow: You can try it with RGB. I will try making the green darker. You may play with RGB composition. Or look on the net for the color you need (RGB)... I will also try to make it check if the parentheses exists

Comment: @Stuck At Home Overflow: Adapted the above code as I said... If you need, the code can transform the range to be processed in string. I clearly asked about this aspect. A formula result cannot have characters in different colors...