# Button to change the color of font in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to create a button in Excel which will change the color of the font in a specific field. Is this possible? Thank you in advance for the support.

I have seen posts outlining below - but havent been able to do it so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CommandButton1.Font.Size = 18
End Sub
```

Comment: How do you define _specific field_? Are you talking about a cell in a sheet or a textbox ...?

Comment: A cell in a sheet, sorry.

Comment: Did you try the macro recorder? It will probaly show you that there is a property _color_ and you could write `.font.color = vbRed`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change font color for a part of text in cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567552/change-font-color-for-a-part-of-text-in-cell)

Comment: @Storax - I have just recorded a macro and this looks to work. Thank you very much. It also works in a text box. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `.Font.Color` from the `.Range` function. Instead of `Range("A1")` use the cell you want to specify and the `RGB()` function returns to you the color according to the RGB code of it. You can check for the color RGB code in many places like [Adobe Color](https://color.adobe.com/create/color-wheel) or clicking at *More Color Options* at Excel Toolbar

[image: RGB and Hex color codes]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Sheet1.Range("A1").Font.Color = RGB(0,0,0)
End Sub
```